# How to invalidate authenticated session in weblogic when the server time outs?

Tags: java, session, authentication, servlets, weblogic

How do I logout the authenticated session in weblogic once the server timeouts as per the configured value in deployment descriptor (web.xml)?

It seems by default server calls `httpSession.invalidate()` method once the server times out. `httpSession.invalidate()` does not logout the authenticated user.

But I need to programatically call weblogic `ServletAuthentication.invalidateAll(HttpServletRequest req)`.

Thought of using `HttpSessionListener` but how do I get hold of the `HttpServeletRequest` object?

Any solution will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When the session is time out, the user is automatically logged out. If you refresh the page you will be redirected to the login page.